# Apply calculations to whole range instead of looping though each cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vectorization

So I have to loop through a range of about 10000 cells containing strings and shortening them to 255 characters. My actual code is like this:

```
For i = firstRow to lastRow
    Range("X" & i) = Left(Range("X" & i),255)
Next i
```

However, this is extremely slow, so I was wondering if there was anyway to do that once on the whole range instead of looping through each cell of the range, or if there was any other way that is more efficient than doing it my way.

Comment: As a general suggestion, if you do get caught making a lot of changes in the spreadsheet that require more operations than a simple array dump, consider temporarily disabling things like [ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub short()

    Dim arr, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long

    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("yoursheetname").Range("X" & FirstRow, "X" & LastRow).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = Left(arr(i, 1), 255)
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("yoursheetname").Range("X" & FirstRow, "X" & LastRow).Value = arr



End Sub
```

When you work with thousands of rows or cells, arrays are the best way to go.

Comment: Forgot completely about storing a range in an array. Gonna try this and accept your answer if performance improves. Thanks!

Comment: This technique is both so useful and so ubiquitous that I create a class to go back and forth for me automatically.

Comment: Hi @PieterGeerkens how would that work? I'm still learning VBA and never toyed with class

Comment: @Damian also i think you can avoid *i=1* and use *i=LBound*

Comment: @Damian: Create a Class Module FastRange. Create a function Initialize (byval Rows as long, byval Cols as long) as FastRange so that the sequence `Dim rng as FastRange: With new FastRange: set rng = .Initialize(45,63): end with` works. Add functions CopyFromRange and CopyToRange with suitable arguments, and an internal REDIM array..

Comment: @Damian so I tried this and it actually performs much faster than my previous aproach. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, FirstRow, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
        FirstRow = 1

        For i = FirstRow To Lastrow
            .Range("X" & i).Value = Left(.Range("X" & i).Value, 255)
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Or**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, FirstRow
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
        FirstRow = 1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 24), Cells(Lastrow, 24))

        For Each cell In rng
            cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 255)
        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How would this go faster? Isn't it doing cell by cell on the excel sheet like his code?

Comment: On a positive note, it does explicitly reference the `.Value` property instead of leaving it to the implicit default reference.

Comment: @Damian you are right about this comment but some times i realize that if you dont use the specific Sheet (clearly declare the sheet before the range), code become very slow. That s why i post a similar code adding the sheet name.

Comment: Is that right? I didn't know... Thankfully I got used to reference always all the workbooks and worksheets to avoid problems so I wouldn't now... What I do know is that `For each` loop is faster to work with cells and `For i` with arrays and collections.

Comment: I m not pretty sure about that, but still on opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("X" & firstRow & ":X" & lastRow)
    .Value = .Parent.Evaluate("LEFT(" & rng.Address & ",255)")
End With
```